# Configure iptables to keep source address on port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, iptables

I want to set up a simple NAT port forwarding rule:

```
external host <-> router <-> server
```

When the external hosts connect to the router's public IP on the forwarded TCP port, a connection to the server is made, but the server log shows the router ip as origin instead of the external host IP. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide the IPTables rules.    What you are describing is pretty default behaviour, you must have a rule which is overriding it - at a guess you are doing NAT on all Interfaces rather then only the outbound one.

Comment: I wish I could. I know it is standard behavior, now I have to convince my client to convince the company in charge of providing and maintaining their network and systems that they are doing things wrong, and I have to be specific enough without having access to their specific configuration. Crazy, right? :-)

Comment: also, thanks for the input. Telling them that they may be doing NAT on all interfaces when they only need to set up a very simple rule in the public one should be a good starting point